# Xamarin Edit Text Keyboard Closes Instantly

Tags: listview, xamarin, textedit

Im using edit texts in my listview. But there are some issues i couldnt understand.

When i touch to Edit Text field sometimes it just closes the keyboard back instantly. I cant understand why is this happening and its happening randomly. Sometimes it opens up and sometimes it closes back. Here is my xml for edit text.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="40.0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:editable="true"
    android:id="@+id/siparis_adet"
    android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yemek_foto"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="280.0dp" />
```

Thanks in the advance

Edit: Turns out its actually not random. It happens when i add more than 3 objects to listview.

Edit 2 : Figured out its not about the count of objects. If keyboard opens and it blocks the view of the listview object keyboard closes back. I still dont know how to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed it by setting keyboard into Adjustpan instead of adjustResize.

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = false, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan)]
```

Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution will fix the issue but it will create a new issue.

In my case when I set the `WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan` the keyboard will not be adjusted based on my recycler view and this will result of making the last items in the recycler view be hidden by the keyboard.

Any advice on that?

Comment: it doesn't look like a valid answer, please use the comment feature instead and once you have a more elaborated answer post it. thanks